# Drawing on picturebox is getting the wrong location

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, drawing, picturebox

im currently having problems while drawing a 'x' into a picturebox by mouseclick.

```
Bitmap currentFahrzeugSchadenImage = new Bitmap(this.SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.Image);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(currentFahrzeugSchadenImage);

g.DrawString("X", new Font("Tamoha", 15), Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.X, e.Y));

this.SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.Image = currentFahrzeugSchadenImage;
```

Im running this on `SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`. The X is always placed somewhere right-under the mouselocation. If i click in the upper-left corner the difference between the mouse and the X is lower then if i click on the lower-right corner.

The `SizeMode` from the `PictureBox` is `StretchImage`.

The dialog:
[image: The Picturebox is within the red]

I hope the problem is clear.

Sorry for bad english.

best regards,
Relax

Comment: What is the `SizeMode` of the `PictureBox`? If it is anything but `Normal` or `Autosize` you will need additional code!

Comment: @TaW the `SizeMode` is `StretchImage`

Comment: The problem is clearly something to do with that `StretchImage`. Question is how to fix it. One straightforward solution would be to draw into something without stretch. So either don't stretch your image or, to example, put something transparent on top of it and draw `"X"` there. If you can calculate ratio (original / current), then multiplying coordinates should also work.

Comment: @Sinatr you were right. The problem was `StretchImage`. Resumed it to `Normal` and now its working fine :) All different images are fitting within the picturebox and if they are too small there is a transparent back. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change this part

```
new PointF(e.X, e.Y)
```

to something like

```
new PointF(e.X * pictureWidth / SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.Width,
    e.Y * pictureHeight / SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a little factor for the stretching, maybe like this:

```
float fx =  1f * SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.ClientSize.Width / currentFahrzeugSchadenImage.Width ;
float fy =  1f * SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.ClientSize.Height / currentFahrzeugSchadenImage.Height;

using (Font f = new Font("Tamoha", 15) )
{
   SizeF size = g.MeasureString("X", f);
   g.DrawString("X", , Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.X / fx, e.Y / fy - size.Height));
}
```

This will work for `SizeModes=StretchImage` and it will put the 'X' **above** the cursor, for easier placement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you might need to do.

First the DrawString function, imagine the text as rectangle the e.X and e.Y coordinates are the top left corner of the rectangle.

Second the e.X and e.Y position that you get might be global so you need to use

```
SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X,e.Y));
```

Comment: After using `SchadenFahrzeugPictureBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X,e.Y));` the X isnt displayed within the picturebox. I think its somewhere else on the screen..